# Assign first 4 characters of the result of a sql query into another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the SQL code below to get a list of computers. I need to somehow take these results and populate another column next to it with just the first 4 characters of each record. For example:

```
Computer Name  New Column

ABCD1000P      ABCD
```

Is this possible?

```
SELECT   SYS.Netbios_Name0
FROM dbo.v_R_System AS SYS 
     INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_PROCESSOR AS Processor ON SYS.ResourceID = Processor.ResourceID 
     INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM ON SYS.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID
WHERE (SYS.Obsolete0 = 0) AND (SYS.Client0 = 1)and SYS.Netbios_Name0 not like '%-%'
```

Comment: Does the query your posted output `ABCD1000P`?

Comment: Yes, I just need to now get ABCD into a new column

Comment: You mean you want to another select column, so both Computer Name and New Column should be returned?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `LEFT` function

```
SELECT S.Netbios_Name0 AS ComputerName, LEFT(S.Netbios_Name0, 4) AS NewColumn
FROM dbo.v_R_System AS S
INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_PROCESSOR AS P ON S.ResourceID = P.ResourceID 
INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM AS C ON S.ResourceID = C.ResourceID
WHERE S.Obsolete0 = 0
AND S.Client0 = 1
AND S.Netbios_Name0 NOT LIKE '%-%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a derived table:

```
select dt.Computer.Name, LEFT(ComputerName,4) as NewColumn
(
SELECT   SYS.Netbios_Name0 as ComputerName   
FROM         dbo.v_R_System AS SYS INNER JOIN
                  dbo.v_GS_PROCESSOR AS Processor ON SYS.ResourceID = Processor.ResourceID INNER JOIN
                  dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM ON SYS.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID
WHERE     (SYS.Obsolete0 = 0) AND (SYS.Client0 = 1)and SYS.Netbios_Name0 not like '%-%'
) dt
```

**Edit**: `LEFT`, not `SUBSTR`. Thanks Matt!

Comment: My instant thought was SUBSTR as well!